# Why anchor outline is not visible when wrapped in a div?

Tags: css

I have two link images, one of them is wrapped in a `div`:

[image]

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  margin: 100px;
  gap: 40px;
}

a {
  outline: 4px solid red;
}

img {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="https://google.com">
    <img src="https://as2.ftcdn.net/v2/jpg/01/36/70/67/1000_F_136706734_KWhNBhLvY5XTlZVocpxFQK1FfKNOYbMj.jpg" alt="smiley" />
  </a>
  <div>
    <a href="https://google.com">
      <img src="https://as2.ftcdn.net/v2/jpg/01/36/70/67/1000_F_136706734_KWhNBhLvY5XTlZVocpxFQK1FfKNOYbMj.jpg" alt="smiley" />
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

To get rid of the unwanted whitespace at the bottom of the link I added `display: block` to the image:

```
img {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  display: block;
}
```

But, now, the link that is wrapped in `div` doesn't have an outline:

[image]

Why is this happening? What's the best way to fix this?

Comment: vertical-align: top to the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the link itself is still `inline`, and so the `block` image simply "flows" out of it.

Make the link itself `inline-block`, or `block`, or `inline-flex`, something that is *not* `inline`.